# How I collect texts divided by CSS selector?

Tags: python, css, selenium

I intended to get texts next to the div-class like below codes.

```
<div class="review-contents__text">소재가 좀 저렴해 보이지만 그래도 입으면 휠씬 나아보여요</div>
```

First, I make a code like this.

```
        texts_outer_review1 = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.review-contents > div.review-contents__text")
        outer_TextData.append(texts_outer_review1)
```

But, It shows what seems to be interpreted in Selenium lib as captured image [image]

Can I get the texts next to class names By codes?:

1. texts_outer.review1.texts()
2. driver.find_elements(...).texts()

I will try to run codes above, But I don't know it's right.
Or Should I add more sentences in 'driver.find_elements'?

Answer (score 1):

what you just need is 'text' attribute.
but as you used find_element's' method, you would have list type.
so the solution is

```
result = [element.text for element in texts_outer_review1]
```

or

```
result = [element.get_property('text') for element in texts_outer_review1]
```

and you can append or extend(cause the result is list type) on outer_TextData